# How to import Javascript module to angularJs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, tabulator

I want to use Tabulator in AngularJs. My code simply is:

```
 var table = new Tabulator("#example-table-remote", {
            ajaxURL: "/Home/Getpaging",
            pagination: true, //enable pagination
            paginationSize: 10,                
            paginationMode: "remote", //enable remote pagination
            ajaxURLGenerator: function (url, config, params) {
                const { page, size } = params;
                return url + `?page=${page}&size=${size}`;
            },
            ajaxResponse: function (url, params, response) {                  
                let last_page = response.MyData.last_page;
                var mydata = JSON.parse(response.MyData.lstHotel);                   
                return {
                    data: mydata,
                    last_page,
                };
            },
             autoColumns:true,

        });
```

if I just add my code to my project (not inside of AngularJs controller ) and import following module to my project.

```
import {TabulatorFull as Tabulator} from 'tabulator-tables';
```

all Tabulator's modules work fine. But if I just move my code to my AngularJs controller, I get the error:

> Tabulator is not defined

if I add tabulator js file directly, the above error disappeared but I get a new error. The new error is:

> Data Loading Error - Unable to process data due to invalid data type
> Expecting: array
> Received:  object

This is because of AngularJs controller can not read modules.
I want to know how can I import modules to my angularJS project.

Comment: Do you use a bundler for your project?

Comment: @jabaa not I do not

Comment: You can either use a bundler to bundle the imports or use the import feature of the browser https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules I guess the path is wrong in your current code. I have no idea how `import {TabulatorFull as Tabulator} from 'tabulator-tables';` could possibly work for you in the described environment. You should provide a [mcve].

Comment: I add `import {TabulatorFull as Tabulator} from 'tabulator-tables'`; in the AngularJs controller file, and it works. thanks. your idea about the bundle really helps me.

Answer (score 0):

You can include Tabulator using CDN in the `index.html` file of your app.

In `index.html` `<head>` add:

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.1.4/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.1.4/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
```

This would include tabulator in the global scope of the window. `import` would not be required here, and is not usually the right way of including modules in AngularJS.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks but as I said if I add those CDN  to my project it just loads the basic, not the module. I work around and solve my problem by adding `import` to the file my AngularJs controller exists.

Comment: I was able to get this running to some extent on Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/poNRTMlm4bvo6jXH

Comment: your code does not work. And It is not what I want. I answered my question. you can check my plnkr

Answer (score 0):

I checked and thanks to @jabaa  I find the solution:
First, I add `import` in my the AngularJs controller file. Then I change the file type to `module`

Here is the working [Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/2JSPBac9GwW4mvDB)